# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session in Mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, firefox

I am fairly new to selenium and trying to invoke the Firefox browser using the following java code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class google {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/gowtham/Desktop/Selenium/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following exception on my console.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@7d70d1b1, version=, platform=ANY, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@2a742aa2}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:47:51 -0800'
System info: host: 'system', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:2acf:e9ff:fe19:261%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:293)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
    at HelloWorls.google.main(google.java:11)
```

I have firefox v52.0 installed on my machine.

Please share your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: When you run the code does the browser launch? If not you may have the browser installed in a custom location and would have to specify it like: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.bin", "/path/to/bin"). See: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: Yes, the browser launched but it didn't navigate to google.com. I just resolved this issue by degrading the gecko driver to the previous version 0.14.0.

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comments so far, so post the way to resolve this problem here.
Indeed, gecko driver version needs to be downgraded. 
For those, who are using 'bonigarcia-webdrivermanager', add driver version explicitly before instantiating FirefoxDriver:

```
FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup("0.14.0");
```